# Computing FIRST and FOLLOW sets

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers

Suppose we have the following grammar:

```
S -> A ( S ) B | ε
A -> S | S B | x | ε
B -> S B | y
```

where `S` is the start symbol, `S, A, B` are non-terminal symbols, `x, y, (, )` are terminal symbols, and `ε` is the empty string.

I'm trying to compute the `FIRST()` and `FOLLOW()` sets of `S`, `A`, and `B`.

```
FIRST(S) = FIRST(A ( S ) B) ∪ {ε}
FIRST(A) = FIRST(S) ∪ FIRST(SB) ∪ {x} ∪ {ε}
FIRST(B) = FIRST(S B) ∪ {y}
```

How can I compute `FIRST(S)`, since I don't know what the `FIRST(A)` is? How should I attack the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know fix points ?

Comment: @FrançoisGodi No, they really mean `A ( S ) B`. The parentheses here are alphabet symbols.

Comment: Stavros, you can look at https://www.site.uottawa.ca/~bochmann/SEG-2106-2506/Notes/M2-3-SyntaxAnalysis/index.html the second example.

Answer (score 1):

If you just keep applying FIRST, it not hard to understand where to stop.

FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) =  FIRST($\mathtt {A(S)B}$) ∪ {ε}

In your example, FIRST($\mathtt{A}$) includes ε, so

FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) = FIRST($\mathtt {A}$)\{ε} ∪  FIRST($\mathtt {(S)B}$) ∪ {ε} = FIRST($\mathtt {A}$)\{ε} ∪ {$\mathtt{(}$} ∪ {ε}

Now, as FIRST($\mathtt{A}$)\{ε} = FIRST($\mathtt{S}$)\{ε} ∪ FIRST($\mathtt{SB}$)\{ε} ∪ {$\mathtt{x}$}, then

FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) = FIRST($\mathtt{S}$)\{ε} $\cup$ FIRST($\mathtt{SB}$)\{ε} ∪ {$\mathtt{x}$} ∪ {$\mathtt{(}$} ∪ {ε}

Notice that the appearances of $\mathtt{S}$ on the left side are redundant here, so we get (again, because FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) includes ε):

FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) = FIRST($\mathtt{B}$)\FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) ∪ {$\mathtt{x}$} ∪ {$\mathtt{(}$} ∪ {ε}

The end result is FIRST($\mathtt{S}$) = {$\mathtt{y}$, $\mathtt{x}$, $\mathtt{(}$, ε}